# Automatically updating dropdown after change event

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list which is populated via a jquery ajax call when another dropdown list is changed, on the change() event, the code which does this:

```
    //dropdowns switching        
        $("#eventActivity").bind("change", (function()
        {                     
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo site_url('events/get_locations_for_activity'); ?>" + "/" + $(this).val(),
                data: "activityID=" + $(this).val(),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    //empty the ddl
                    $(".locationDDL").children("select:first").children("option").remove();
                    //go through the json data returned and edit the drop down
                    for( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
                    {
                        $(".locationDDL").children("select:first").append("<option value=\"" + data[i].locationID + "\">" + data[i].name + "</option>");
                    }

                }
            });
        })).change(); //force change to run once so it works on load for the first dropdown option
```

Now these dropdowns are on a dialog which pops up when the "edit" button is clicked.  I'm passing the data through to the edit dialog so I can pre-fill the fields on the dialog.  It all works fine except for setting the dropdowns to the correct values.
The code I use to do this is here:

```
$("#eventActivity").val(event.activityID);
$("#eventActivity").change(); //force the change handler to update the dropdowns
$("#eventLocation").val(event.locationID);
```

As you can see, I set the value of the first dropdown, trigger the change event which should load new values to the second dropdown, then set the value of the second dropdown.
The problem is that the third line of code (setting #eventLocation) doesn't work, instead the dropdown is left with it's default value selected, the first value in the drowdown list.

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I forgot the mention, the HTML for the dropdowns is trivial, just 2 <select> with the id's "eventActivity" and "eventLocation".

Comment: You should use jQuery trigger to activate event "change" works like this $('#eventActivity').trigger('change');

Comment: $("#eventActivity").change(); should work, see: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: why wont u set the value of second dropdown in the `ajax` success call back

Comment: Are your sure that your function actually gets data? I don't think this line of code is doing what you want: url:"<?php echo site_url('events/get_locations_for_activity'); ?>". It should be something like this: url:<?php echo "\"".site_url('events/get_locations_for_activity')."\""; ?>

Comment: Aaron - yes, the function gets data. I use the same type of call in many other places, plus this mechanism (setting dropdowns) works fine on another form.  The only difference on the other form is the need to set the first dropdown value programmatically.

Comment: 3nigma - if you read above, you'll see that the ajax success call is for filling the second dropdown with the correct set of options.  Setting the value of the second dropdown must be done via another event, in this case when the "edit" button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the value of the last dropdown in the success callback of your ajax request. If the last value setting depends on the ajax request being complete, you should have it in the callback. It is likely your request hasn't been completed by the time that last value setting happens.

Comment: The ajax request is part of the change event which is generic as this pairing of dropdowns occurs elsewhere, but without the added complexity of then setting a value in the resulting second dropdown.

I can see what you are suggesting, and that is to do another ajax request and setup the dropdowns when I click "edit" so that in the success portion I can then set the value.

However, I'd hoped to not have to create a special version just for this one instance, but it seems like I may have to.